# Is it possible to control which cell's border prevail?

Tags: html, css, colors, border

Here are four 2x2 tables, each having a single cell with a dark border.  I'd like the dark border to stand out but unfortunately the adjoining light borders cover parts of the dark one in somewhat random ways.  Is there a way to force a given cell's border not to be covered by adjoining ones?

I thought of using `z-index`, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin:auto;
  }

td {
  padding: 10px;
  }

td.dark {
  border: 8px solid black;
  }

td.light {
  border: 8px solid lightgrey;
  }
```

```html
<table>
<tr> <td class="light"> a </td> <td class="light">b</td> </tr>
<tr> <td class="light"> a </td> <td class="dark">b</td> </tr>
</table>

<br>

<table>
<tr> <td class="dark"> a </td> <td class="light">b</td> </tr>
<tr> <td class="light"> a </td> <td class="light">b</td> </tr>
</table>

<br>

<table>
<tr> <td class="light"> a </td> <td class="dark">b</td> </tr>
<tr> <td class="light"> a </td> <td class="light">b</td> </tr>
</table>

<br>

<table>
<tr> <td class="light"> a </td> <td class="light">b</td> </tr>
<tr> <td class="dark"> a </td> <td class="light">b</td> </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Maybe instead of setting a full border try setting border-bottom, border-top, border-left, etc. for individual cells of light/dark and manually adjust from there.

Comment: Thanks fot your comment but I've already tried it without sucess :-(

Comment: Just found a solution by accident: set the dark border's width 1px larger than the light ones and everything works fine.  However this sounds a bit like a cheat so I'd still be interested in a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *border-collapse mechanism* gets in the way with this. The easiest solution is use absolute postioned `::before` or `::after` with either a `border` or a `box-shadow` to create the border.

The snippet shows both solutions with `::after`.

Beware:

- Because of the `border-collapse`, class `.dark` will still need a `border`, but its color is irrelevant as it will be overlayed with our custom border
- Either `::before` or `::after` will overlay the content of the table cell making it hard (but *not* impossible) for the user to select the content.

**snippet**

```css
body { display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap; gap: 2rem; justify-content: center }

table { border-collapse: collapse; margin:auto }
td    { padding: 10px }

/* still need .dark border to trigger border collapse */
td.dark  { border: 8px solid black } /* color is irrelevant */
td.light { border: 8px solid lightgrey }

/* Solutions */

/* ::before/::after will overlay the table cell, this may be unwanted behavior     */
td:is(.s1,.s2)::after { background-color: CornSilk } /* to show overlay of ::after */
/* Just disable this rule, remove it or use 'transparent' as color value */

:is(.s1,.s2).dark        { position: relative }            /* new stacking context */
:is(.s1,.s2).dark::after { position: absolute; content: '' }  /* relative to .dark */

/* Solution 1, using 'border' */
td.dark.s1::after {
    inset: -8px; /* shorthand for top: -8px; right: -8px; bottom: -8px; left: -8px; */
    border: 8px solid black
}

/* Solution 2, using 'box-shadow' */
td.dark.s2::after {
    inset: 0; /* shorthand for top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; */
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 8px black
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr> <td class="light"> a </td> <td class="light">b</td> </tr>
<tr> <td class="light"> a </td> <td class="dark">b</td> </tr>
</table>

<table>
<tr> <td class="dark"> a </td> <td class="light">b</td> </tr>
<tr> <td class="light"> a </td> <td class="light">b</td> </tr>
</table>

<table>
<tr> <td class="light"> a </td> <td class="dark s1">b</td> </tr>
<tr> <td class="light"> a </td> <td class="light">b</td> </tr>
</table>

<table>
<tr> <td class="light"> a </td> <td class="light">b</td> </tr>
<tr> <td class="dark s2"> a </td> <td class="light">b</td> </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

According to `CSS` guidelines this is a defined behavior of `border-collapse`.

> If collapsing borders have the same style and width, but differ in
> color, then from most to least preferred: cell, row, row group,
> column, column group, table.
>
> If come from same type of element, such as two rows then color is
> taken from borders that are the topmost and the leftmost.

```css
table {
  margin: auto;
}

td {
  padding: 10px;
}

td.dark {
  border: 8px solid black;
}

td.light {
  border: 8px solid lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="light"> a </td>
    <td class="light">b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="light"> a </td>
    <td class="dark">b</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="dark"> a </td>
    <td class="light">b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="light"> a </td>
    <td class="light">b</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="light"> a </td>
    <td class="dark">b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="light"> a </td>
    <td class="light">b</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="light"> a </td>
    <td class="light">b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="dark"> a </td>
    <td class="light">b</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

OR you can have your own `<td>` styling for each row `<td>` element.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  However, for reasons that have to do with my specific real world problem, I must use `border-collapse`